# Word for politicians and judges

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe a group of politicians and judges?
The best I came up with is "public figures" which is both too wide (there are lots of public figures which are not politicians or judges) and too long. Is there a single word grouping or describing politicians and judges?

Comment: it's a good question.  in some contexts, "administration"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most specific term I can think of that encompasses both is **official**, but it may not be narrow enough for your purpose.

> **official**
>
> *noun: official; plural noun: officials*
>
> 1. a person holding public office or having official duties, especially as a representative of an organization or government
>      department.
>    <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/official)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Office holder](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/office-holder?q=officeholder): A person who holds a position of authority or service, especially within a government or government organization.

Answer (score 1):

That can be a magistrate, but by his ancient meaning:

In ancient Rome, a magistratus was one of the highest government officers and possessed both judicial and executive powers.

But it's more a person with both the role of a politician and a judge than a group of those two types of people.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't too fussy, *legislators* will be understood. Technically, judges administer the law rather than make it, but anyone involved knows the line is a fuzzy one, and only matters if you are discussing fine constitutional points.